# Is it possible to execute a mutation or query locally at server side with Apollo Server

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

I would like to know if it is possible to execute a mutation or query locally at server side with Apollo Server.

Example:

1- Endpoint GET /createNew is reached

2- I run a mutation I defined like:

```
apolloserver.mutation(mutation_query).then((response)=>{res.status(200)})
```

3- A new entry is added to the database and a JSON string is returned to client

Does something like that exist? Is a `apolloserver` object available at runtime?

I'm using NodeJS + Express

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it working

First we start the objects:

```
import express from 'express';
import { graphql } from 'graphql';
const context = require('./context'); //this is the object to be passed to each resolver function
const schema = require('./schema'); //this is the object returned by makeExecutableSchema({typeDefs, resolvers})
const app = express();
```

Then, if we want, for example, to run a query on endpoint `GET /execute`

```
app.get('/execute', function(req, res){
    var query = `
        query myQueryTitle{
            queryName{
                _id,
                ...
            }
        }
    `;

    graphql(schema, query, null, context)
    .then((result) => {
        res.json(result.data.queryName);
    });
})
```

So anytime we want to run a query or a mutation, we call `graphql` passing `schema`, the `requestString`/`query` and the `context` object

And this may coexist with an instance of `graphqlExpress`

Comment: While this works, it's not actually executing through Apollo Server but instead, it just uses the execute method in graphql.js. This is fine as long as you don't use any Apollo middleware (such as Apollo Engine) since they won't run in this case.

Comment: Is there a solution for that problem @PetrBela - I'm looking into a solution like this - and we are using Apolloe Server 